# Is it required to sanitize parameters of curl (called from a bash script) filled with user inputs?

Tags: security, openvpn, bash-scripting, curl, escaping

Is it safe to run curl in a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

response=$(curl --data-urlencode "user=$username" --data-urlencode "pass=$password" https://my-api-url)
```

with username & password coming as environment variables populated with arbitrary user input. This is for a authentication script called by a OpenVPN server.

Comment: What do you mean by safe? Do you mean in regards to how you're storing the credentials

Comment: Safe in the sense that a maliciously crafted input cannot be used to run arbitrary commands.